# Cortana wont open certain programs due to spelling

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I've been using cortana, but I've run into a problem. I was hoping to get her to open a program called CorelDRAW X3 but she always hears "corele instead of corel." Is there any way I can change this or make another shortcut?

Comment: Why not make a shortcut and change it's name to "corele draw"?

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: Start menu shortcuts

Comment: Hi, my first language is not English. so I am not sure that if my thought is current. I think that the two word `corele`, `corel` should have different pronunciation. How about slower and currently. Hope this can help you.